# trying to make a console app guessing game? is my logic correct?

Tags: java

My "If" statement aren't giving me the write answer, for example if I input "5" it prints too high which mean the random number is lower but if i input a lower number like "4" it prints too low which would mean the random number is higher. Its pretty confusing, Am just wonder if my logic in the code is correct??

import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.lang.Math;

public class GuessTest
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   System.out.println("Welcome to the gussing game, Try to guess the number am thinking of to win!");
   System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
   System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Am thinking of a number between 0 and 10. Try to guess it.");
    System.out.println();

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String choice =  "y";

   while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
   {

     System.out.println("Enter the Number:");
       int guess = sc.nextInt();
       double rightNum = Math.random() *10;
       int randomNum = (int) rightNum;


       if (guess == randomNum)
       {
           System.out.println("Correct you've got it! The Number Was " + randomNum );
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
           choice = sc.next();
       }
     else  if (guess < randomNum)
       {
           System.out.println("your too low!");
       }
     else if (guess > randomNum)
       {
            System.out.println("Your too high!");
       }   

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calculating the random number on each `while-loop` iteration. Just calculate it once by moving the calculation code out of the loop:

```
double rightNum = Math.random() *10;
int randomNum = (int) rightNum;
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
    //your logic...
}
```

---

Since you want to have several game rounds, you can recalculate the random number when accepting a new game:

```
double rightNum = Math.random() *10;
int randomNum = (int) rightNum;
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
    //your logic...
    if (guess == randomNum) {
        System.out.println("Correct you've got it! The Number Was " + randomNum );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            rightNum = Math.random() *10;
            randomNum = (int) rightNum;
        }
    }
    //your logic...
}
```

Comment: You would also need to recalculate the value if the accept another round

Comment: @MadProgrammer haven't noticed. Thanks for the tip, answer updated.

Comment: Still got a +1 regardless ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just realized that my `boolean` option was wrong (just like the meme)

Comment: @MadProgrammer IF I place the choice to continue within the guess == random if clause, it won't recalculate a different random number when they press y to play again??

Comment: I would, personally, set the randomNum to a negative value, and in the main loop re-calcualte the value when ever it is below 0

Answer (score 0):

Well, your logic is sound... but the code is rather flawed. You want the program to generate a random number, and then have the player guess it based on whether they are too high or low, but your have the computer pick a different random number each time.

Try placing

```
double rightNum = Math.random() *10;
int randomNum = (int) rightNum;
```

just outside of the while loop. That may fix your problem (But of course it will create more regarding the choice to continue).

Comment: so If I place the choice to continue within the guess == random if clause, it won't recalculate a different random number when they press y to play again??

Comment: If you place it in the guess ==random clause it will still create a new value. The only problem is that the place you have it creating a random number right now does not work. What Luiggi Mendoza suggested should work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Not to take anything away from what has already been suggested, this is simple "another" way it could be done...

```
public class GuessWhat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the gussing game, Try to guess the number am thinking of to win!");
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Am thinking of a number between 0 and 10. Try to guess it.");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        int randomNum = -1;
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

            if (randomNum < 0) {
                randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the Number:");
            int guess = sc.nextInt();


            if (guess == randomNum) {
                System.out.println("Correct you've got it! The Number Was " + randomNum);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
                choice = sc.next();
                randomNum = -1;
            } else if (guess < randomNum) {
                System.out.println("your too low!");
            } else if (guess > randomNum) {
                System.out.println("Your too high!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Basically, I simply recalculate the random value if the `randomNum` is ever below 0.  When the user guesses correctly, I simply reset the `randomNum` to `-1`

Comment: I tried that and doesn't make a difference, random number wont be recalculated it will stay the same.